# Prevent mac from requiring login screen at home

Tags: macos

I would like to prevent my mac from sleeping when I'm at home. I trust the people in my house, and would like to stop it from being locked.

Or even better, maybe it could only require a password after 30 minutes?

Answer (score 1):

If you open terminal and type `caffeinate` it will never sleep until terminal is quit (when you get home).

Comment: Thanks Pete. Maybe it's possible to make some sort of unix command that runs caffeinate as a certain WIFI connects?

Comment: Sorry I don't have time to do it properly but would probably be something like

` connected=$(ifconfig -l)

if fgrep "YOUR NETWORK SSID" <<< $connected
then
caffeinate
else
back to start`

Would need a loop most likely.- if you need help I will try to come back to it later :)

Comment: Thanks Pete. I will look into this when I have more time.